# Launch console application from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I have a simple game in separate solution. There are some classes and so on. How to launch it from WPF by pressing the button?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\PathToYourOtherApp\YourApp.exe");
```

This will start your other process.

Comment: Is it possible to make it in one solution? To add it like another project, maybe add some references. My game is .sln so i want to make it like one solution.

Comment: Well, yeah, just right-click your solution > Add existing project.

Comment: and how then launch this project from main wpf project? Sorry for making myself not clear enough.